# .NET Core 2.2 best place to store Profile Images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently writing a small web app and one of the requirements is to have a profile image on the top right corner. So far placement has been fine. However, I am concerned about where the profile images are being stored.

At the moment, I am using a folder in the wwwroot to store them. However, if there are too many users, I am worried that the size of the folder will become too big.

I have an idea of storing it in another folder outside of my webroot and contentroot folder. Something like in the C:\Inetpub\vhosts\AppOneContent folder.

However, for some reason I cannot get the url for the staticfileoption to work. It always returns a 404. However, it works if I do something like stream a FileResult back.

This is my StaticFiles section in my Startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:\Inetpub\vhosts\AppOneContent\Profiles"),
    RequestPath = "/Profiles"
});
```

My intention is to make this folder another wwwroot where there can be a url to access the items inside.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Clouds, clouds and again clouds :)

Comment: I understand but the problem is that using the cloud is another implementation for later. Is there a library I can use to do what I want to do now?

Comment: Use some storage service. ex: Azure Blob. Storing in file system may not be a scalable solution.

Comment: Can you add how your url looks like that one which returns 404.

Comment: www.dev.appone.com/Profiles/userA/image.png removing userA also produces the same result

Comment: in that C:\Inetpub\vhosts\AppOneContent\Profiles what do you have userA/image.png?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? In the Profiles folder I have a folder specific to a user and in the folder contains the Image.png file

Comment: I just discovered why its not working. My dev.appone.com link had to have the applications name in it. I can't believe I missed that one out.

Comment: @JianYA  to store your file in local disk ,you should sepreate the file by month or year , forexample  /files/2019/09/file1.jpg

Comment: Clouds. Go with Azure Blob or AWS S3 buckets.